# ArcSDE register with gdb vs register as versioned

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, file-geodatabase

When wanting to update tables within a sde gdb, is there a difference between registering as versioned vs registering with the gdb vs registering with sde?  I've read the question below and it hints that versioning is a subset of gdb registration.

I am hearing that Unregistering a table as versioned will allow the use of sql to update the table, I assume directly from say SSMS.

We are at ArcGIS for Server 10.1 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

[Difference between registering with ArcSDE and registering with Geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62522/difference-between-registering-with-arcsde-and-registering-with-geodatabase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely!  Registering a table with ArcSDE creates metadata in the SDE
user SDE_* tables.  Registering a table with the geodatabase does an 
ArcSDE registration *and* populates XML metadata in the SDE.GDB_* tables.
Registering as versioned registers with the geodatabase *and* enables the
ArcSDE versioning capability on the table.  As such, I wouldn't describe
versioning registration as a subset -- it's more of a superset, though
it is possible to enable versioning on a table without geodatabase
registration (just not through the ArcGIS UI or via ArcObjects or Python).

Unregistering a table as versioned removes versioning.  You can always 
update a versioned base table via a SQL client, but doing so will corrupt
the version tree of the instance (not exactly a recommended activity). 
Note that unversioning does not unregister a table -- the cleanest way
to do that is to delete the table via ArcGIS (often with a 
"CREATE TABLE newname AS SELECT * FROM tablename" to make a backup of 
the table contents first).

Comment: Could you comment on updating a table registered with ArcSDE but not versioned.  I found something in the docs about generating objectids but why would this be needed?

Comment: If a table is registered with ArcSDE *and* has an SDE-set registered rowid, then a SQL UPDATE should not change the rowid column value. INSERTs should be done through the ArcSDE API to generate correct rowid values, though it is possible to use the documented procedures to preserve rowid integrity via SQL.